# Invoke WCF method in Generic Class property with Reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, reflection

I have the following class:

```
 Public Class WcfClient(Of T)

        Private _Cliente As T

        Public ReadOnly Property Client As T
            Get
                Return _Cliente
            End Get
        End Property
```

T, represents a Wcf Channel, that is created like this:

```
Dim channel As New ChannelFactory(Of T)(basicHttpBinding, remoteAddress)
'Set the property
 _Cliente = channel.CreateChannel()
```

Now, with reflection, I am creating an Instance of WcfClient, and I want to execute a Method that is inside the Client Property.

```
Type tipo = FindInterface(Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()[0]);
Type genType = typeof (WcfClient<>).MakeGenericType(tipo);
var client = Activator.CreateInstance(genType);    
var clientProp = client.GetType().
                GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "Client").FirstOrDefault();

 if (clientProp != null)
 {

    var method =clientProp.PropertyType
                   .GetMethod(Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()[1]);
     ProcesoBase procesoBase = new ProcesoBase();

     foreach (var prop in typeof (ProcesoBase).GetProperties())
     {
          //Here we have some code to fill ProcesoBase properties   

      }

    }

  var result = method.Invoke(clientProp, new object[] { procesoBase });
```

When calling method.Invoke I am getting `Object does not match target type` in exception

I am getting the MethodInfo class from the clientProp variable so I don't get it how this is happening.

Could this be because the generated Channel class is built as proxy_TransparentProxy class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by getting the client Property using the GetValue instead of using the GetProperties:

```
  PropertyInfo p = client.GetType().GetProperty("Client");
  MethodInfo m = p.PropertyType.GetMethod(Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()[1]);
  object clientProp = p.GetValue(client);
```